# Change cell value based on adjacent cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a table where column B has data, some are which are "Port". Column C has a specification. I need to make a macro that iterates through column B and for those cells that contain "Port" AND the port is something different than 22, 3181 or 3389 it changes the value of the cell in column B to "Port+".

The formatting in column c varies, so it can be "Port22, port22, port_22" etc. Sample below:

> |Port | Port3181
>   |Port  | port_3389
>   |URL   | abcd
>   |SQL  |  qwerty
>   |Port |  Port 5900
>   |Port  | Port22

I have a piece of code that works for a specific port, but I don't know how to make include all 3 of the above ports to the criteria.

```
If ActiveCell Like "Port" And Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) Like "*3181*" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Port+"
```

This feels quite clumsy though, maybe someone knows a better way to do it? I have multiple worksheets where the last row varies, so I would like to make the loop section somehow dynamic so I can use the same macro for all worksheets.

EDIT:

Well this is what I came up with:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do
i = i + 1

If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "Port", vbTextCompare) > 0 And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) Like "*22*" _
Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) Like "*3181*" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) Like "*3389*" _
Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Port" Else ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Port+"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop Until i = 40
```

It's working now in the sense that it changes the cell in column B to Port+ when the port is something else than the 3 designated. However it's also changing non-port entries where column B has something else than "Port" to Port+ also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't provided much code to go on but

```
If UCase(ActiveCell.value) Like "*PORT*"
```

or

```
If Instr(1, Activecell.value, "Port", vbtextcompare) > 0
```

would both provide case insensitive comparisons

for varying rows if there is a column that should always have data in it you can use

```
Cells(rows.Count, "A").end(xlup).row
```

to get the last populated row assuming you know the data is not filtered